# Conditional regex - what does ? do in the given scenario

Tags: regex, regex-group

What does this exactly do?

```
(?(1)yes|no)
If capturing group 1 was matched so far, matches the pattern before the vertical bar. Otherwise, matches the pattern after the vertical bar. A group name, or a relative position (-1) in PCRE, can be used
```

I see the following example (found in regex101.com)

```
/(candy)?(?(1) is true| is false)/
candy is true is false.
```

In the above case 'candy is true' is matched.

```
/(candy)?(?(1) is true| is false)/
canndy is true is false.
```

I now modified `candy` to `canndy` in the input string and now ' is false' is matched.

However if I remove the ? in the middle (i.e the one just after (candy)), it doesn't match anything in the second case. So my question is - what role is that ? exactly carrying out?

Comment: `(candy)?` makes this match an optional match so group 1 may or may not exist.

Comment: @anubhava - Thx ... but isn't that already factored in based on the definition, "If capturing group 1 was matched so far, matches the pattern before the vertical bar. Otherwise, matches the pattern after the vertical bar". That's where my confusion stems from

Comment: The conditional syntax varies depending on regex flavour. What language/tool are you using?

Comment: @Toto I was checking that out with the pcre mode

Comment: @Traveller: If you don't make that capture group an optional match then it will always fail when `candy` is not present (even before conditional construct is processed).

Comment: Perhaps this page can be helpful https://www.rexegg.com/regex-conditionals.html